# No data receiving with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsurlsession

My post request works fine (I have a good response and no error) but I have no data receiving too..
Normally when I am on my browser on this site https://conventiondestage.insa-toulouse.fr/index.php I complete the form and after login I can see the content of the page accueil.php but why my function does not return data (I want the html content of this page) ?

Thanks for your help !

This is the log in console :

```
2014-04-07 17:52:00.207 myINSA[22797:60b] Response:<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x14e92d50> { URL: https://conventiondestage.insa-toulouse.fr/accueil.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 1428;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Mon, 07 Apr 2014 15:52:00 GMT";
    Expires = "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15, max=100";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny16 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny16";
} } (null)
2014-04-07 17:52:00.210 myINSA[22797:60b] Data = (null)
```

This is my function :

```
- (IBAction)pushLogin:(id)sender {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://conventiondestage.insa-toulouse.fr/index.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString * params =@"login=myLogin&password=myPass";
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [urlRequest addValue:@"max-age=0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"keep-alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"https://conventiondestage.insa-toulouse.fr" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Origin"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"gzip,deflate,sdch" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"https://conventiondestage.insa-toulouse.fr/index.php" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Referer"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"conventiondestage.insa-toulouse.fr" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                           NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                           if(error == nil)
                                                           {
                                                               NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                               NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                                           }

                                                       }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

I have the same result with this code :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://conventiondestage.insa-toulouse.fr/index.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *post =@"login=mylogin&password=mypass";
    [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"Data = %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: but are you able to get the data in you server??

Comment: Why that Cache-Control header for the POST request? Why no Content-Type header? Your session will leak memory, please read the official docs.

Comment: I edited my message.
I have this information about header with a chrome extension.

Comment: second edit with a new code but same result...